# ¿Como hacer sub´s menus en python?

Tags: python

Hola quiero hacer sub´s menus en python, he intentado pero me quedo estancado.
Anteriormente me habia ayudado mariano

El codigo:

```
print"""

1) Herramientas               3) fye

2) Noticias                  4) Mas...
"""

eligio=raw_input("-Selecciona algo : ")

if eligio=="1":
print("""
    Listamos las herramientas para...



    1) Otro                   2) otro""")

   eligio=raw_input("-Selecciona algo : ")

   elif eligio=="2":
   x = 3
   y = 5
   print("x * y = ", x * y)
  elif eligio=="3":
  print("Que noticias?")
 elif eligio=="4":
 print("otra opción")
 else:
print("Opcion no valida")
```

El error es el siguiente :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "python", line 23
   elif eligio=="2":
   ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Sin embargo si quito eligio=raw_input("-Selecciona algo : ") sigue funcionando como antes

Lo estoy corriendo en python 2.7, Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se abra un menu se pueda seleccionar otro y otro

Gracias

Comment: revisaste la indentación?

Comment: Cono? Trate de cambiarle algunas cosas pero sigue igual :/

Comment: Estas respetando la sintaxis? Porque a mi me funciona el primer menu y el segundo también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con estas modificaciones a mi me funciona

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

menu = '1) Herramientas               3) fye\n'
menu += '2) Noticias                  4) Mas...'
print menu

eligio = raw_input("-Selecciona algo : ")

if eligio == "1":

    submenu = 'Listamos las herramientas para...\n'
    submenu += '1) Otro                   2) otro'
    print submenu

    eligio = raw_input("-Selecciona algo : ")

elif eligio == "2":
    x = 3
    y = 5
    print("x * y = ", x * y)
elif eligio == "3":
    print("Que noticias?")
elif eligio == "4":
    print("otra opción")
else:
    print("Opcion no valida")
```

Si quieres hacer algo mas interesante, te recomiendo esta excelente libreria, [python-prompt-toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit)

Comment: Gracias a los 2 por ayudarme

Comment: :O estare viendo esa libreria gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hola tu error es un error de sintaxis, se produce porque intentas crear el submenu empezando por un `elif`. En la estructura `if-elif-else` el `elif` siempre va después de un `if`. Al crear tu submenú creas un nuevo bloque de código que está dentro del primer `if` (no a su nivel, sino dentro) por lo que tienes que empezar con un `if`. Sería algo así:

```
print("""

1) Herramientas               3) fye

2) Noticias                  4) Mas...
""")

eligio = input("-Selecciona algo : ")

if eligio=="1":
    print("""
Listamos las herramientas para...

    1) Opcion 1                   2) Opcion 2""")

    eligio = input("-Selecciona algo : ")

    if eligio == "1":
        print("Ha selecionado opcion 1")
    elif eligio == "2":
        print("Ha selecionado opcion 2")
    else:
        print("Opcion no valida")

elif eligio == "2":
    print("Que noticias?")
elif eligio == "3":
    print("¿Que es fye?")
elif eligio == "4":
    print("otra opción")  
else:
    print("Opcion no valida")
```

Comment: Mmm Gracias estare viendolo gracias por responder :D cualquier error te aviso

Comment: Aunque el que colocaste tambien me da error de sintaxis

Comment: Asegurate de poner en la punta del archivo `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, ya que caracteres no ASCII en el código, como la **ó** de la line `print("otra opción")`

Comment: Si, se me habia olvidado el utf, sin embargo me aparece esto Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 33
    print("Opcion no valida")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Ya lo he corregido, es que al copiar el codigo aqui se me habian ido algunas identaciones al garete.... Creo que ya esta bien.

Comment: Gracias a los 2 por ayudarme